# wordpress update meta not working

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, meta

hey i am trying to update user meta but its not updating

```
  $dobs=$_REQUEST['day'].'_'.$_REQUEST['month'].'_'.$_REQUEST['year'];
  $gender=$_REQUEST['gender'];
  $country=$_REQUEST['country'];
  $state=$_REQUEST['state'];
  $city=$_REQUEST['city'];

  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'date_of_birth', $dobs, true );
  update_user_meta((int) $user_id, 'gender', (int) $gender, true );
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'country', $country, true );
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'state', $state, true );
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'city', $city, true );
```

here i tried typecasting like (int) (string) interesting part is insert working properly don't know if there is an error in DB structure.

Comment: try after removing 4th argument of  `update_user_meta( $user_id, 'date_of_birth', $dobs );`

Comment: do you have a $user_id ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the 4th param of the `update_user_meta`

`update_user_meta( $user_id, 'date_of_birth', $dobs );`

The 4th param is used by wordpress to update only the fields that have a previous value equal with the value of the 4th param

So wordpress is looking for  `date_of_birth` that has a previous value of true for that user

more [info](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/meta.php#L211)

Answer (score 0):

> update_user_meta() - Update user meta field based on user ID. It has only three arguments in general where the 4th is optional.  The 4th parameter is the `$prev_value` which in default will be the '' values alone. Hence the 4th parameter will be checking whether the `meta_key` updated has the previous values to it.

For Example:

```
<?php
     $user_id = 1;
     $website_url = 'http://wordpress.org';
     update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_url', $website_url, TRUE); 
    // The above statement will update the user_meta table corresponding to the user_id=1
?>
```

Note: The First 3 Parameters are required. Without that it will not work.

Kindly ensure that the the 'second value' in the update_user_meta() should be existing into the database table.

As per the Question Author Scenario:

```
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'date_of_birth', $dobs, true );
```

It must have all the 3 parameters namely `$user_id`,`date_of_birth` and the `$dobs`.

Comment: no it has 4 arguments, the 4th is `$prev_value` which is optional

Comment: Ya edited for that alone and added up the quote over there.

Comment: The one who downvoted please let us know what is the reason.

Comment: you forgot to say what the 4h param does and why its not working for this case

Comment: @madalinivascu. Added up my comments over there for the 4th paramater